# Multi-tenant app accessible by apps in different ADs

Tags: azure, active-directory, cloud

The following image explains the situation quite well

[image]

I would like to allow applications B1 and B2 to access my application A and at the same time, all 3 applications are located in different Azure ADs (Company1 AD, My AD and Company2 AD).

**Is it possible to set up Azure application so that apps in other Azure ADs can access it?**

I'm aware of the "availableToOtherTenants" option in the manifest, but that just seems to allow access for users, not apps. Moreover, when I tried to update the manifest of application B1 or B2 with appId/clientId of application A, the manifest correctly saves, but when I try opening "Required permissions" for B1/B2, it shows the loading animation but never actually loads the resources that I have allowed it to access.

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, what steps do I need to take?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to grant the permission to the application register on the other tenants.

To make it work, we need to create the **service principal** to the tenants which you want to give. For example, we can use the admin consent to register the application to customers' tenant for the organization. To make the request, you can follow the **OAuth 2.0 Code grant flow** from this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/).

After the app register on customers' teant, then they can grant the permission to this app as the app developed in their own tenant. Here is a figure for your reference. And you can refer the [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview/#related-content) for more detail about developing multi-apps with Azure AD.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've been working on it now for a while now, I was able to register the application to customer's tenant by making this admin consent request and I can correctly see the application A in Company1 AD. But when I make a request from B1 to A, A still responds with 401 Unauthorized. I was thinking, don't I need to add B1 as known client to A's manifest? And if yes, how do I go about that?

Comment: It is no need to specify the **know client** to A's manifest. The know client is used to [consent for the multi-tier applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview/#related-content). In this scenario, you app already register on customers' tenant. Then we only need to grant the permission to the customers' app access your app as the last step in the figure above.

Comment: It seems that the B1/B2 (customer's) app is able to access A even without specifically granting permissions to do so. Nonetheless, when adding permissions for B1/B2, I can see application A appear on the list. Either way, everything is now working as I wanted so thank you again!